# memory allocation in real mode in the MBR

Tags: memory-management, x86-16, bios, real-mode, mbr

In a MBR, the following code in the preboot environment allocates a buffer of 10Kb by subtracting 10h from the total amount available :

seg000:7C1D sub word ptr ds:413h, 10h

seg000:7C22 mov ax, ds:413h

seg000:7C25 shl ax, 6

seg000:7C28 mov ds:buffer_segm, ax

I don't understand where exactly does the 10KB allocation come from

I just understand that in the preboot environment, there is no memory manager then the BIOS maintains the number of kilobytes of available memory in a 16-bit value at the address 0:413h.
It's mainly the 2nd and 3rd lines that I don't understand, that is 10Lb allocation ? how ? at which address XXXX:YYYY in real mode ?

Comment: It's actually 16 KiB as 10h in hexadecimal is 16 in decimal. The allocation will be at the end of available base memory. The `word [0:413h]` indicates how many KiB of base memory are available to the OS. This is usually 640 or 639. If you had 640 KiB then ran this code, it would result in a new memory size of 624 KiB and your allocation would be at 624 * 1024 = linear 9C000h (segmented 9C00h:0).

Comment: I've seen what you've written and I can see what it does thanks, but what's the relation with lines 2 and 3? If I follow these lines correctly, I get : 
ax = 413h (no dereference here)     then     ax = 413h x 6h = 1 04C0h

     I don't understand what's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: `mov ax, ds:413h` does not set AX to 413h. You can notice from the segment override that it is a memory load. (Better assembly language syntaxes would indicate this with square brackets.) The adjusted "amount of kibi bytes memory" is loaded into AX. For instance, 624 (270h). This is shifted to the left by 6 bit positions yielding a segment value of for instance 9C00h, corresponding to linear 9C000h. The shift count of 6 is calculated so that from a unit of 1 KiB = 1024 B = 2 ** 10 B you get to a unit of 1 paragraph = 16 B = 2 ** 4 B, as 10 - 4 = 6.

Comment: Apart from the memory load rather than setting AX = 413h, you also got the shift wrong: "then ax = 413h x 6h = 1 04C0h" `shl` doesn't multiply by the second operand, it **shifts** by the second operand. So the 186+ instruction like `shl ax, 6` does AX <<= 6. This is equivalent to multiplying AX by 2 ** 6 = 64. 1 KiB times 64 paragraphs/KiB is 64 paragraphs, 64 paragraphs times 16 bytes/paragraph is 1024 bytes, equal to 1 KiB again.

Comment: Just a side note: a technique used by some virus writers in the old days.

Comment: sorry for the mistake for the shift, I wanted to write 2^6h instead of 6h

Comment: I'm more used to writing with square brackets, I'd forgotten that ds: was a memory load too ok.
The explanation with segments and paragraphs is clear now too, I'm not used to the real mode.
Thanks ecm